# nicedit textarea width inside of jQuery UI accordion not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, textarea, jquery-ui-accordion, nicedit

I am using nicedit.js and jQuery UI accordion.
I have several accordions that contain these nicedit WYSIWYG text areas.

When I refresh the page the first accordion area opens up and displays the correct nicedit WYSIWYG area (Width is 100%).
When I select another accordion area it opens up and displays the nicedit WYSIWYG area but it is only 100px wide.

I did some digging around in the code and found that it uses 100% as a width throughout the building process. I have run into this with jQuery UI accordion not letting things render correctly before and have just destroyed the id and reinitialize it.

I am looking for a solution that will allow all nicedit WYSIWYG areas to render 100% or even a fixed width.

Comment: It's difficult to get the picture... all these accordions and widths. Can you prepare a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or make your page available for us to see ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you subscribe to the accordion's *change* event and initialize the WYSIWYG editors upon those events if they have not been previously initialized. I am not familiar with nicedit or how their editor is constructed, but if it dynamically calculates size then it cannot do so unless the HTML container is visible. Thus the change event will let you have the container visible such that sizes are calculated properly.